# What will happen in Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Suppose x is a linked list node. What are the effects of the following code fragments?

Describe or draw what happens in relation to x?

1. `t.next = x.next;`
   `x.next = t;`
2. `x.next = x.next.next;`
3. `x.next = t;`
   `t.next = x.next;`

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can' understand the point of your question,but it seems you are asking for java assignments and what they affect and how.The answer is,that it depends on what order you have written your fragments.Don't be confused with the class initializations, classes instances are data types,just as Integers.When you read the value of them, you receive the value they had at the moment of the assignment.

In the first situation,`t.next` will point to the `x.next` node and `x.next` will point to t node.Of course,`t.next` will not be affected ,since the value of `x.next` changes after the assignment and will continue to point to where `x.next` was pointing at the beginning.In the third situation,however,`t.next` will be affected and will be pointing at itself,because the assignment happens after the initialization of `x.next`

The second example is obvious;you are practically take out a pointer and set it elsewhere.